# printing pdf file on printer using c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, win32com

In My c++ application (dll) i am printing bitmaps without using print dialogue i.e. from back end code without prompting user to select file. This functionality is working fine.
Now i trying to implement another method that will print already existing pdf file on printer. Exisiting function is specific to bitmaps, i am confused that how i can send pdf file to printer. Following is the working code

```
DOCINFO diDocInfo = {0};
diDocInfo.cbSize = sizeof( DOCINFO );
diDocInfo.lpszDocName = L"printTest";

if( StartDoc( memDC.GetSafeHdc(), &diDocInfo ) > 0 )
{
  if( StartPage( memDC.GetSafeHdc() ) > 0 )
    {   
      CBitmap bitmap;
      CImage frontImage;
      frontImage.Load(_T("C:Test.bmp"));
      bitmap.Attach(frontImage.Detach());

      BITMAP bm;
      bitmap.GetBitmap(&bm);
     int w = bm.bmWidth; 
     int h = bm.bmHeight; 

        // create memory device context
        CDC tempDC; 
        tempDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&memDC);
        CBitmap *pBmp = tempDC.SelectObject(&bitmap);
        tempDC.SetMapMode(memDC.GetMapMode());
        memDC.SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE);
        memDC.StretchBlt(0, 0, 994, 624, &tempDC, 0, 0, 994, 624, 13369376); 

        EndPage(memDC.GetSafeHdc());       
     }
}
```

I am unable to find some way to pass pdf file instead of bitmap to DC

Comment: Before marking as negative, one should write reason and suggest answer so that we can realize that you are not doing it blindly.

Comment: You can use the `pdftocairo.exe` utility from [`poppler`](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/). It will allow you to print directly to the system printer. You just have to find a precompiled binary... or compile your own.

Comment: I am confused that i already have pdf, i don't have to parse or create pdf. I just have to send it to printer. i cannot do it directly? without any external library?

Comment: No, Windows does not use PDF natively. You'll have to do al least one convresion to get there.

Answer (score 1):

A bitmap is raw data immediately accessible to the operating system. PDF files are quite complicated beasts that must be parsed (difficult) and rendered (hard) if written from scratch.

Your best course of action would be using some existing PDF access library (like MuPDF) to do the heavy lifting for you. With that you should either produce a rasterization of the PDF, or vector drawing commands sent to the GDI to print. Fortunately PDF (-1/A) does not do things that can't be mapped to GDI; the hardest part would be processing embedded fonts; if you don't want to rasterize them you'll have to upload glyph data into the GDI context used for printing.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that i already have pdf file, i have to print it only. Do i need to load this file? Can i send this file directly to printer without loading or parsing?

Comment: @Tanveer: Yes, I completely understood you. You will have to parse the PDF file you have to send it to the printer. Although many office grade printers will actually happily accept PDF input sent to them directly over the network you should not rely on that If you were developing for MacOS-X or Linux this would be a non issue since PDFs are used there for actually talk to the printer drivers. But on Windows you have to translate from PDF into GDI calls.